# Unable to get Redux put to work within generator function

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, redux, es6-promise, redux-saga

***Edit 1***

So I have now updated the projectorSaga function to use yield call() as suggested, but I now get the following error every time I call the function, which I think is due to the way I have nested the functions and returning promises not functions that return promises, but I'm at a bit of a loss as to how to restructure this to fix it.

```
redux-saga error: uncaught at check
call: argument [object Promise] is not a function
[14:57:43.351] [verbose] Error: call: argument [object Promise] is not a function
```

Here's the update saga code, other functions are still as below.

```
import { put, takeEvery, call } from 'redux-saga/effects';

import * as pjControl from '../../pjcontrol/pjControl';

import { TURNON, TURNOFF, SENDCOMMAND, SHUTTERCLOSE, SHUTTEROPEN } from '../actions/actionTypes';

const log = require('electron-log');

const ip = '192.168.100.100';
const port = 3629;
const model = 'L1500';

function* sendCommand(payload) {
  yield put({ type: 'SENDING COMMAND', payload });
  try {
    let response;
    const command = payload.payload.command;
    if (command === TURNON) {
      response = yield call(pjControl.turnOn(ip, port, model));
    } else if (command === TURNOFF) {
      response = yield call(pjControl.turnOff(ip, port, model));
    } else if (command === SHUTTERCLOSE) {
      response = yield call(pjControl.shutterClose(ip, port, model));
    } else if (command === SHUTTEROPEN) {
      response = yield call(pjControl.shutterOpen(ip, port, model));
    } else {
      throw Error('Unknwon Command');
    }
    log.verbose(response);
    yield put({ type: 'SEND_COMMAND_SUCCEEDED', response });
  } catch (e) {
    log.verbose(e);
    yield put({ type: 'SEND_COMMAND_FAILED', e });
  }
}

export default function* projectorSetSaga() {
  yield takeEvery(SENDCOMMAND, sendCommand);
}
```

***Original***

I've just started trying to use Redux-Saga in an Electron application I've been working on, and I am having issues getting a put to work in one of my generator functions. I suspect it's me not understanding the nesting of say functions and callback e.t.c, but I've tried this in many many ways so far and no difference.

The oddness of the issue is that the initial yield in sendCommand does cause an event to appear in Redux. Also the log commands I have in place do get called when I would expect them to, with the correct values. And if the connection times out, the log in the catch get's called, but neither of the throw commands ever appear in Redux.

This is my root Saga:

```
import { all, call } from 'redux-saga/effects';

import projectorGetSaga from './projectorGetSaga';
import projectorSetSaga from './projectorSetSaga';

export default function* rootSaga() {
  yield all([
    call(projectorGetSaga),
    call(projectorSetSaga),
  ]);
}
```

And this is projectorSetSaga, which I'm struggling with.

```
import { put, takeEvery } from 'redux-saga/effects';

import * as pjControl from '../../pjcontrol/pjControl';

import { TURNON, TURNOFF, SENDCOMMAND, SHUTTERCLOSE, SHUTTEROPEN } from '../actions/actionTypes';

const log = require('electron-log');

const ip = '192.168.100.100';
const port = 3629;
const model = 'L1500';

function* sendCommand(payload) {
  yield put({ type: 'SENDING COMMAND', payload });
  try {
    let response;
    const command = payload.payload.command;
    if (command === TURNON) {
      response = yield pjControl.turnOn(ip, port, model);
    } else if (command === TURNOFF) {
      response = yield pjControl.turnOff(ip, port, model);
    } else if (command === SHUTTERCLOSE) {
      response = yield pjControl.shutterClose(ip, port, model);
    } else if (command === SHUTTEROPEN) {
      response = yield pjControl.shutterOpen(ip, port, model);
    } else {
      throw Error('Unknwon Command');
    }
    log.verbose(response);
    yield put({ type: 'SEND_COMMAND_SUCCEEDED', response });
  } catch (e) {
    log.verbose(e);
    yield put({ type: 'SEND_COMMAND_FAILED', e });
  }
}

export default function* projectorSetSaga() {
  yield takeEvery(SENDCOMMAND, sendCommand);
}
```

Here is the rest of the code for the functions the saga is calling as it might be relevant, I may have completely misunderstood the way the async function/promises e.t.c need to be returned.

The PJ Control function that the sendCommand function is calling is as follows.

```
import * as epsonControl from './epson/epsonControl';
import { manufacturerlLookup, commandLookup } from './pjLookups';

function sendCommand(ip, port, model, command, input) {
  const manufacturer = manufacturerlLookup(model);
  const mappedCommand = commandLookup(manufacturer, command, input);
  switch (manufacturer) {
    case 'epson':
      return epsonControl.sendCommand(ip, port, mappedCommand);
    default:
      return null;
  }
}




exports.turnOn = (ip, port, model) => sendCommand(ip, port, model, 'PWR ON');

exports.turnOff = (ip, port, model) => sendCommand(ip, port, model, 'PWR OFF');

exports.shutterOpen = (ip, port, model) => sendCommand(ip, port, model, 'MUTE OFF');

exports.shutterClose = (ip, port, model) => sendCommand(ip, port, model, 'MUTE ON');

exports.setInput = (ip, port, model, input) => sendCommand(ip, port, model, 'SOURCE', input);

exports.getPowerStatus = (ip, port, model) => sendCommand(ip, port, model, 'PWR?');

exports.getShutterStatus = (ip, port, model) => sendCommand(ip, port, model, 'MUTE?');

exports.getInputStatus = (ip, port, model) => sendCommand(ip, port, model, 'SOURCE?');
```

And finally, the actual function that is async, and is actually returning a promise with return/throw.

```
exports.sendCommand = async (host, port, command) => {
  log.info(`sending command ${command} to ${host}`);

  // throw new Error('Oh dear!');
  // Set a time to cancel the operation if the connection times out
  const mergedCommand = `${command}\r`;
  // Create a new client
  const socket = new net.Socket();

  socket.setTimeout(1000);

  const client = new PromiseSocket(socket);

  await client.connect({ host, port });

  await client.write(buildBuffer(handshake));

  client.stream.on('data', (data) => {
    if (data.toString() === response) {
      log.verbose(`Got handshake, sending command ${command}`);
      client.write(buildBuffer(mergedCommand));
    } else if (data.toString() === ':') {
      // log.verbose('command executed successfully, disconnecting');
      sendStatus(data.toString(), host);
      client.end();
      return (true, 'command');
    } else {
      const respose = data.toString().substring(0, data.toString().length - 2);
      // log.verbose(`got status ${response} disconnecting`);
      sendStatus(respose, host);
      client.end();
      return (true, 'command', data);
    }
  });
};
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you're `yielding` (pausing) the generator function without calling next on it. Saga has functionality for this. For example instead of yielding on a function call, you yield on the saga function `call`.

So it should be :

```
 try {
    let response;
    const command = payload.payload.command;
    if (command === TURNON) {
      response = yield call([pjControl,'turnOn'],ip, port, model);
    } 
 ...
```

Please see https://redux-saga.js.org/docs/api/

Comment: Hi Dennie, that makes complete sense, and now I've read the docs I understand that saga is just continuing execution I think. However I now seem to be stuck in a bit of a world of incorrectly nested promises/returning promises. Have edited the above with the error and updated code, any additional help would be most appreciated!

Comment: Instead of `yield call(pjControl.turnOn(ip, port, model));` use the signature I suggested: `yield call([pjControl,'turnOn'],ip, port, model);`

Comment: Dennie is correct.  You should leverage `call`.  I think you can also do the following `yield call(pjControl.turnOn, ip, port, model);`

Comment: Thanks, those both call the function as expected, however I still have the same issue with the yield put not getting called in either of the success or failure outcomes, for instance I can see the error get logged when the connection times out, but nothing gets despatched into redux.

Comment: There's absolutely no reason for that. Maybe the generator gets cancelled somehow. Please try to make a small (online) example that shows this behaviour and I can take a look

Comment: Let me try and repackage it into something a little simpler, though it’s a currently an electron app that has a primary store in the main process and a secondary synchronised store in the renderer, so it will take some work. I can put the whole project up on GitHub, shouldn’t take more than a git clone and a yarn install, then npm run to get it up and running if you want to see the whole setup?

Comment: This sounds like a matter of debugging.  Without a live example (and I understand, its difficult to pull redux-saga into a jsfiddle), its hard to help.  My best advice from the information given would be sticking console logs around your code and see where its failing.  I haven't found stepping through line by line in generator functions very easy to do in dev tools.  You can also add in a `finally` block and log there, which will always get called.  Good luck :)

Comment: Ok so I have this worked out, and it was multiple things creating the issue.
First issues was not using the yield call() as suggested by Dennie. Second issue was the resolve not being returned correctly from the async function, which I have fixed by converting it to a full promise. Finally, I am using electron-redux to sync the store between main and the renderer. I am viewing the redux state via the web debugging tool within Electron, which is within the renderer, and I wasn't calling properly FSA compliant actions from redux-saga, so they where not being passed to the renderer.